# Connecting to sqlite in iphone development

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I have used sqlite database in some of my iphone applications but as you know it is a lot harder than other languages such as java and php to use database. Is there any way to use database easier !? I found a framework in sourceforge here : http://mysql-cocoa.sourceforge.net/ but I think it is not for cocoa-touch. Is there any other framework to ease the sqlite pain !?
thanx alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb)

It's an sqlite Wrapper and works with IPhone.

Or use [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). It's not a database wrapper, but an object graph persistence framework, which may be what you want.

Comment: +1 If your going to be doing iOS apps, you really need to learn Core Data. Going forward, no one is going to maintain solid SQL wrappers for iOS because Core Data is so clearly superior and easy to use. Why spend so much time duplicating functionality that Apple already supplies. How much of market is there in people who know SQL in C but can't take the time to learn Core Data? Core Data has a learning curve but in use it is way, way simpler to implement and faster at runtime than any direct SQL implementation.

Comment: Thanx alot. FMDB is great. I haven't tested CoreData yet. I will test that later too.